# SLES 12.2 can't enable org.gnome.Vino - No such key 'enabled'

Tags: gnome3, vnc, suse, sles

Since Sles 12 SP2 I'm not able to activate VNC remote access:

```
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.Vino authentication-methods "['vnc']"
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.Vino vnc-password $(echo -n 'basis2k'|base64)
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.Vino enabled true
```

> No such key 'enabled'

The key is also missing when trying to activate it with dconf-editor:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestion.
I managed it by installing x11vnc. To start it i created a systemd unit file "/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service":

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc-Server

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /root/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

With the commands `systemctl enable x11vnc` it will automatically start at system boot. You can also manually start it with `systemctl start x11vnc`

I hope this will work in future SuSE releases.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I had to do on CentOS 7 (I know it's not SLES 12.2).  @Sebastian answer helped a lot, but I still needed to find one more setting "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.sharing active true".  I also wanted to enable it on all my Ethernet (IEEE802) interfaces (wired/wireless):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino authentication-methods "['vnc']"
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino vnc-password $(echo -n 'my_password'|base64)
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.sharing active true
eths=$(nmcli -t -f uuid,type c s --active | grep 802 | awk -F  ":" '{ print "'\''" $1 "'\''" }' | paste -s -d, -)
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.sharing.service:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/sharing/vino-server/ enabled-connections "[ $eths ]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since GNOME 3.14 `vino` is started by the network dependent sharing plugin of `gnome-settings-daemon` rather than a simple autostart. You can configure this in the sharing settings of `gnome-control-center` or if you prefer to use `gsettings` the command is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.sharing.service:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/sharing/vino-server/ enabled-connections "['UUID']"
```

where `UUID` is the UUID of the network connection you want to enable it for. Enabling it for multiple UUIDs/connections is also possible using the format `"['UUID1', 'UUID2']"`. You can find the list of all UUIDs using `nmcli c`.